# Why for motion planning of quadrators the goal is to minimize the jerk/snap?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, non-linear-systems, linear-systems, equations-of-motion

In motion planning for quadrators the optimization goal is sometimes to minimize the (norm squared of the) jerk and more often the (norm squared of the) snap. Can someone provide an intuitive and theoretically explanation? What optimization goal is used for cars in general (i.e. velocity, acceleration, jerk)?

Answer (score 0):

Sudden changes in velocity (accelerations) and sudden changes in acceleration (jerks)  are felt by humans as unpleasant sensations. Vehicle and road design are therefore conducted in such manner as to minimize those sensations.

For example, in laying out railroad track turns, the entry radius is established to furnish both acceleration and jerk profiles that have zero derivatives at the turn entry point.

In machine design, suddenly applied loads can excite unwanted resonances in the machine and also initiate fatigue cracking, and so measures need to be taken to minimize their presence (for instance, by adding compliance to things like motor mounts and drive shafting).

Comment: Can you explain the example of railroad track turns a bit further? Are you talking about when a train switches the railroad?

Comment: Moreover, can this also be related to the control effort and can you show it with the equations of motion for cars?

Comment: the railroad track turns: the transition from a straight section of track to a curve of some radius has to be made so smoothly that the first and second derivatives of the curve are zero at the transition point. I cannot show it for the car case.